# Connect to SharePoint Online using an external user using c# and Client Side Object Model (CSOM)

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, office365

I'm trying to connect to SharePoint Online website using c# and Client Side Object Model (CSOM). I'm an external user and can access the URL using my browser but when I try that programmatically, it fails saying - The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system. Following is the code sample that I have tried. I have the correct username/password. Any help is appreciated.

To add clarity - my external user looks like       myemail#EXT#@companyname.onmicrosoft.com  (the @ sign inmyemail is replaced with an underscore).

```
string siteUrl = "https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/ERCT";
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    var psd = "Password".ToCharArray();
    SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in psd) secureString.AppendChar(c);
    //psd.ToList().ForEach(secureString.AppendChar);

    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username@companyname.onmicrosoft.com", secureString);
    SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");

    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";

    ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.Load(collListItem,
    items => items.Include(
        item => item.Id,
        item => item.DisplayName,
        item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments));

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nDisplay name: {1} \nUnique role assignments: {2}",
        oListItem.Id, oListItem.DisplayName, oListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use proxy to connect to the internet? That could be the reason too

Comment: @Matt - it could be. Is there a way I confirm? As I said I'm able to connect using a browser window.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it works fine on my tenancy.  I installed the "Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM" nuget package.  Maybe try:

```
uninstall-package "Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM"
install-package "Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM"
```

Also, try running this in a new Console App.  Depending on your app.config there maybe settings around proxies etc.

If that doesn't help you could also try [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to watch the calls.

EDIT:  Also try using the email address of the external user by itself as the login name.

Comment: Did you try with an external user? A user that's not in your Domain. I'm also able to connect using an internal user.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that SharepointOnlineCredentials works with external users from a different tenant. I could not get it to work for users not defined to an o365 tenant.

As stated by CodeMonkey, there is a newer set of csom libraries you will need to get using Nuget.  Install Nuget package 'Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM' - this will replace your references with newer versions of the CSOM libraries.
Refer to: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/using-correct-csom-version-for-sharepoint-customizations/

Answer (score 0):

CSOM has dependency on UserProfile service, if SharePoint does not find user in user profile, it simply does not authenticate users.

thus external users are not part of user profiles that's why they can't be authenticated using CSOM.